# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am making a simple blackjack simulator in python to get used to object oriented programming and practice counting cards. The simulator looks like this for so far

```
import random
cardvalues = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, 
"8": 8, "9": 9, "10":10, "J": 10, "Q": 10, "K": 10, "A": 11}
class Shoe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        amount = input("how many decks do you want in the shoe?\n>")    
        self.shoe = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"] * amount * 4
        self.shoe = random.shuffle(self.shoe)
    def deal(self):
        pcard1 = self.shoe.pop()
        pcard2 = self.shoe.pop()
        comcard1 = self.shoe.pop()
        comcard2 = self.shoe.pop()
        handworth = cardvalues[pcard1] + cardvalues[pcard2]
        print "You have been dealt a {} and a {}. The value of your cards is {}".format(pcard1, pcard2, hadworth)
        print "The dealer has a {} and an other card that's faced down.".format(comcard1)
class play(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "welcome to blackjack simulator!"
        print "You shall be playing at a 100 dollar minimum table, with a wallet of $5000,00"
        my_shoe = Shoe()
        my_shoe.deal()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

and the error was

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I quickly discovered that the problem here was that the line

```
self.shoe = random.shuffle(self.shoe)
```

turned my entire self.shoe list into None instead of shuffling it. Can someone please explain why this happened and how to fix it?

Nevermind, I have solved the problem myself. As it turns out, I used the random.shuffle command wrong. When I removed the "self.shoe = " it ran without errors.

Comment: `_init_` should be `__init__`. Not sure it would help in this case, but have  you tried to use a linter? Pycharm has builtin one and in command line you can use `pylint`.

Comment: You are using the print statement and not the print function, that means that you are using some Python 2.x. There is no excuse, when learning python nowadays to not start with the latest Python from the 3 series i.e. 3.6.1. Get an up-to-date tutorial that uses Python3

Comment: I would also suggest that `amount` be passed as an argument to the `__init__` method of Shoe

Answer (score 2):

since the __init__ is mistyped as _init_, the constructor is never invoked and so the attribute self.shoe is never set. So when deal() is executed, the attribute does not exist

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that! It fixes that problem, but now I have another one. After I have shuffled the card, it turns my list into None. Do you know why that happened and how I should fix it?

Comment: random.shuffle happens in place, and returns None. This means the value of the argument is altered, instead of returning an altered version of the argument.  
So you need to type just random.shuffle(self.shoe) instead of assigning it to self.shoe

Comment: Seriously though, don't make more work than you need. Use `random.sample`

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
cardvalues = {"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, 
"8": 8, "9": 9, "10":10, "J": 10, "Q": 10, "K": 10, "A": 11}
def deal():
    cards, values = zip(*random.sample(cardvalues.items(), 2)))
    print("You have been dealt a {} and a {}. The value of your cards is {}".format(*cards, sum(values)))
```

Okay, I've pointed out the original issue in my comment, so I wouldn't repeat myself (besides OP have already fixed that).
As to why I showed another solution - because it's better. Better how?

1. It doesn't creates classes where a [function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0&t=3s) would be sufficient.
2. It doesn't creates unnecessary intermediate data structures (`self.shoes`)

So to summarize - to make your code better watch the video in the link and don't make classes without the need for them. Use `random.sample` instead of creating list, shuffling it and then popping from it. And of course use python3!

Comment: Care to add a little bit of explanation?

Comment: Explanation of what? api of `random.sample` or `zip`?

Comment: What the original issue was and how you solved it. Or rather, why you did not help to solve the OP's issue but chose to offer an alternative approach.